Getting a collection back from ExactInputSingleParams in Uniswap V3, not the swap amount value
I'm using ethers.js and typescript to call a contract's swap function: ExactInputSingleParams in Uniswap V3,and getting a collection returned with many different elements in it, rather than the output returned new token amount of the swap.   Swap succeeds fine.   How do I get the amount of the new token in the exchange?
    Typescript call:

            var outputAmount: any;
    // Swap Tokens 
    
    if (! --iterations) {
       outputAmount = await contractSwapDex.swapTokens(token0Address,
            token0Amount,token1Address,0,dexType,timeout,router,
            poolFee, true); }      
    else  {
        outputAmount = await contractSwapDex.swapTokens(token0Address,
        token0Amount,token1Address,0,dexType,timeout,router,
        poolFee, false);
    }

    console.log("Output Amount: \t", outputAmount);


   Solidity Contract Code:

            // Perform swap
            uint256 swap_amount_out = 0;
            uint256 amountOutMinimum = 0;
            uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
                .ExactInputSingleParams({
                    tokenIn: _tokenPath[0],
                    tokenOut: _tokenPath[1],
                    fee: _v3_fee,
                    recipient: address(this),
                    deadline: block.timestamp,
                    amountIn: _amountIn,
                    amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum,
                    sqrtPriceLimitX96: sqrtPriceLimitX96
                });
            swap_amount_out = pancakeswapV3.exactInputSingle(params);




Output Amount:   {
  hash: '<hash data>',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '<block hash data>',
  blockNumber: 213082472,
  transactionIndex: 3,
  confirmations: 16,
  from: '<Metamask Wallet Address>',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "10000001" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "12656250" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "203447" },
  to: '<Swap Contract Address>',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 138,
  data: '<data>',
  r: '<hash data>',
  s: '<hash data>',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 42161,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}

